# Google Maps Not Resizing in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have Google Maps on my page and am trying to have it resized when the window size changes.

This is what I have going on in Dreamweaver:

- Google Maps shows up: Map's Width is 617px
- Google Maps doesn't show up (white box instead): Map's Width is 100%
  <-- what I want it to do

The funny thing is, on jsfiddle it works EXACTLY the way I want it to, but in Dreamweaver it's not doing the same thing. I want to know what are some possible things I'm missing or doing wrong.

Link to [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zuyky26h/). Here's my CSS code, which might be relevant:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
#map-dining{
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
}
```

---

SOLVED

I am helping someone with their website, and saw that they had another CSS page linked to the site. I kept taking out small sections of the code until I pinpointed the culprit.

```
.neighborhood-btns {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

When I changed the position from absolute to relative, the map was able to resize with the window. Thank you all again for the patience, I am a novice and am still learning :)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  The problem must be due to something on your wordpress page that isn't on the fiddle, probably CSS and/or HTML.

Comment: Are you saying that it's not working in Dreamweaver design view or that it doesn't work when you open the page in a web browser? Dreamweaver's design view does not always provide an accurate representation of what your pages will look like in a real web browser.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your patience. When I open the page in a web browser, Google Maps does not show up. The code I have in Dreamweaver is the same code that I have in JS Fiddle, I'm guessing it's either the CSS or HTML like geocodezip says